# throws a function in react for tag names, how to debug that function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When I print the tag names it throws a function
**console.log(SportsPage);**

Do you guys know the reason?

Providing my code below:

```
console.log(SportsPage);
<SportsPage name={this.props.name} completed={status.state.status}>
    <Input
        sportsRefrence={sportsRefrence}
    />
</SportsPage>
```

Comment: @all why did you guys mark it negative...since I formatted the code its not showing up...

Comment: some kind of odd bug prevented the code from showing up after the list (adding line-breaks or `<br>` or a string of text did not fix it). Odd, never seen that before. I fixed it by removing the (pointless) list.

Comment: It throws a function. What happen when you do `console.log(SportsPage());`?

Comment: @GitaarLAB can you give much more explaination I didnt understand this line :( ----> I fixed it by removing the (pointless) list.

Comment: @AlonEitan when I do ` console.log(SportsPage()); ` it throws a not a function error...can you tell me the reason I am trying to learn js :(

Comment: I fixed the text of your question-post (to show the code you included from the start) by removing the un-ordered list formatting (bullet points) that you used to format your question.

Answer (score 0):

This code uses [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html), which is a Javascript syntax extension. It's tempting to think of JSX as HTML but this is **wrong** - it compiles down to Javascript. React uses functions to create elements. When you `console.log(SportsPage)` you are logging the instance of the `SportsPage` class that you have defined elsewhere (aka, your React component) and Javascript classes [are just functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

As for debugging, you almost always want to debug the *props* and *state* of your components, but not the component instance itself. React provides some great [lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) for this. For instance if you notice your component is rendering more times than expected, you could check out the props and state it is receiving and compare to what it already has in the `componentWillUpdate` method.

Comment: but can't I go inside SportsPage function to see whats happening... :(

Comment: @texirv What exactly do you want to see happening? React provides a bunch of lifecycle functions that you could log from, like `componentWillReceiveProps` which fires right before it receives new props and you can compare with old ones. Is that the type of thing you are looking for? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: when I watch SportsPage in console it shows not available do you know the reason behind it

Comment: @texirv I would avoid using `object.watch()` as it is not supported in all browsers and even its own documentation warns against using it. What specifically are you trying to watch? Again, if you want to log every time the state changes or the props change you can do that in those lifecycle methods, like `componentWillReceiveProps`. I can expand my answer to include info on that if that's what you're trying to see.

Comment: I am not using object.watch() I was using developer tools watch in console feature

Comment: @texirv okay but what are you trying see happening? React is fairly complicated under the surface and a lot is going on when it is rendering an element to the page. But you don't really need to watch the internals unless you are interested in contributing to the source code itself. Instead you really only care about your component's *data* (state and props) and its lifecycle.

Comment: @texirv I went ahead and updated my answer to talk about lifecycle methods. Let me know if this is helpful to you or if you are still trying to watch something else.

Comment: but we where not using any lifecycle methods like componentWillUpdate in my jsx file...

Comment: @texirv You can use them wherever you have defined the `SportsPage` component.